# Retry Oozie workflow action in Hue (CDH4)

Tags: oozie, hue, cloudera-cdh

how to set retry failed oozie workflow actions in hue (CDH 4.6), i didn't see any option to do that in workflow editor

**oozie log**

2014-05-15 14:30:01,784 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[test] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Test] JOB[0000189-140514123627882-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000189-140514123627882-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000189-140514123627882-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : **userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]**

**oozie confiuration in hue :**

oozie.service.LiteWorkflowStoreService.user.retry.error.code   JA008,JA009,JA017,JA018,JA019,FS009,FS008
oozie.service.LiteWorkflowStoreService.user.retry.inteval 10
oozie.service.LiteWorkflowStoreService.user.retry.max 3

how to set retry count? can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the options is not yet available: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2114